# Cannot open file:// URLs on Android

Tags: python, android, file, browser

I'm trying to make my Python script open a local HTML file in the browser, or at least in web view, on Android (app Pydroid3).
Given that I specified the filename in `filename`:

```
# method 1
import webbrowser, os
webbrowser.open("file://"+os.path.realpath(filename))
```

This results in the message:
`Cannot open file:// URLs on Android`.

*I am unable to find the first error **as a sentence** in a web search, is this error **this** uncommon?*
When I un-quoted it I found only this other proposal:

```
# method 2
from urllib.request import pathname2url
url = 'file:{}'.format(pathname2url(os.path.abspath(filename)))
webbrowser.open(url)
```

This results in a toast stating:
`Unable to start activity for android.intent.action.VIEW/file:/storage/emulated/0/folder/filename.html`

How can I make it work?

Comment: I do not believe that webbrowser.open(url) would cause a message unable to start activity.

Comment: Here's what I see: https://youtu.be/gKzRrSp_cLc. Do you mean that the cause is somewhere else?